# Looping over a SQL result with multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a "source table" which holds some rows, in this case four. Now I'd like to insert new rows into a "target table" for each of the rows from the source table.

My current statement is:

```
SET @id = 1;
INSERT INTO target_table (id, value)
VALUES (@id, 1),
       (@id, 2),
       (@id, 3),
       (@id, 4);
```

However I'd like to do something like this...

```
SET @id = 1;
myResultSet = SELECT value FROM source_table;
FOR EACH value in myResultSet
    INSERT INTO target_table (@id, @value)
END
```

Comment: Why do you want to have all id values as 1 in your target_table ?

Comment: It's the ID of a "fixed employee" who can have multiple permissions.

Comment: Ok. you simply need to use a [`Insert ... Select`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Insert ... Select`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) statement:

```
INSERT INTO `target_table` (`id`, `value`) 
SELECT 1, `value` 
FROM `source_table`
```

Completely possibilities of this statement can be seen from the syntax below:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    [(col_name [, col_name] ...)]
    SELECT ...
    [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE assignment_list]

value:
    {expr | DEFAULT}

assignment:
    col_name = value

assignment_list:
    assignment [, assignment] ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO target_table ( id, value )
SELECT  row_number() OVER (order by <whatever>) , value FROM source_table
```

or

```
INSERT INTO target_table( id, value )
SELECT  1, value FROM source_table
```

depending on what you mean

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO target_table( id, value )
SELECT  1, value FROM source_table
```